# Calculate duration from multiple rows and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table `session_logs` in PostgreSQL 10.5 with the following entries:

```
| id  | session_id | recorded_at              | powered | camera_blocked |
| --- | ---------- | ------------------------ | ------- | -------------- |
| 1   | 2          | 2019-06-26T13:40:00.000Z | true    | false          |
| 2   | 2          | 2019-06-26T13:45:00.000Z | false   | false          |
| 3   | 2          | 2019-06-26T13:50:00.000Z | false   | true           |
| 4   | 2          | 2019-06-26T13:55:00.000Z | false   | false          |
| 5   | 6          | 2019-06-26T13:45:00.000Z | true    | false          |
| 6   | 6          | 2019-06-26T13:50:00.000Z | false   | false          |
| 7   | 6          | 2019-06-26T13:55:00.000Z | false   | true           |
| 8   | 6          | 2019-06-26T14:00:00.000Z | false   | false          |

---
```

And I want to write a query that will give me the following results

```
session_id started_at           ended_at            power_dur battery_dur camera_blocked_dur
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          2019-06-26 13:40:00 2019-06-26 13:55:00   5        10          5
6          2019-06-26 13:45:00 2019-06-26 14:00:00   5        10          5
```

How do I go about writing a query that can correctly sum these values while grouping by `session_id`? I have the following but it does not group correctly:

```sql
with session_log_lead as (
    select sl.*, lead(recorded_at) over (order by recorded_at) as next_recorded_at
    from session_logs as sl
)
select session_id, min(recorded_at) as session_start, max(recorded_at) as session_end,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered) as powered_duration,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered is false) as battery_duration,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where camera_blocked) as camera_blocked_duration
from session_log_lead
group by session_id
```

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oC2w76QKuS5R4BapiqExW/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `PARTITION BY` in your window function to calculate by each *session_id*:

```
with session_log_lead as (
    select sl.*, lead(recorded_at) over (partition by session_id order by recorded_at) as next_recorded_at
    from session_logs as sl
)
select session_id, 
       min(recorded_at) as session_start, 
       max(recorded_at) as session_end,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered) as powered_duration,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered is false) as battery_duration,
       sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where camera_blocked) as camera_blocked_duration
from session_log_lead
group by session_id
order by session_id;
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/PYJUT39105)

Additionally for integer values of minutes, add `EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM ...)` to the aggregates:

```
EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered)) as powered_duration,
EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where powered is false)) as battery_duration,
EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM sum(next_recorded_at - recorded_at) filter (where camera_blocked)) as camera_blocked_duration
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and thanks for the bonus info on EXTRACT minutes :)

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help. Happy coding!